# двумерный массив объектов на основе таблицы

Tags: lua

Следующий код на  Lua:

```
define class Cell
Cell = {xPos = 0,
        yPos = 0,
        …..}
local Cells = { {}, {} }
function Cell:new (o, xPos, yPos)
      o = o or {}
      setmetatable(o, self)
      self.__index = self
      self.xPos = xPos
      self.yPos = yPos
                ….

    return o
end   

-- init matrix of cell class instances
for i = 1, 10, 1 do
       Cells[1] = {}
      for j = 1, 20, 1 do
           Cells[i][j] = Cell:new(nil, i, j)
       end  
end
```

В результате выполнения этого кода значения полей классов в матрице устанавливаются в следующие значения:

```
Cells[1][1].xPos = 10
Cells[1][1].yPos = 20
…
Cells[1][2].xPos = 10
Cells[1][2].yPos = 20
…
Cells[10][20].xPos = 10
Cells[10][20].yPos = 20

Но я ожидал такой результат:
Cells[1][1].xPos = 1
Cells[1][1].yPos = 1
Cells[1][2].xPos = 1
Cells[1][2].yPos = 2
```

Что я делаю неправильно? Перепробовал разные варианты, но ожидаемого результата не получил.

Заранее спасибо за подсказку

Comment: `Cells[1] = {}` — предполагаю, что здесь задумывался индекс `i`, а не единица.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

1. у вас опечатка в строке:

   ```
   Cells[1] = {}
   ```

   исходя из логики окружающих конструкций, вместо `1` должна быть переменная `i`.
2. я, увы не специалист по *lua*, поэтому не улавливаю, для чего вам нужен первый аргумент в функции `Cell:new`, но, в любом случае, вы используете одну и ту же переменную `self` для всех создаваемых экземпляров (подобный случай упоминается, например, в [этой](https://habrahabr.ru/post/228001/) статье, как «наивный вариант конструктора»). вам надо либо добавить в начале этой функции присвоение:

   ```
   self = {}
   ```

   либо уже так и пользоваться переменной `o` вместо `self`.

полный, слегка подкорректированный тест (второй вариант закомментирован):

```
--define class Cell
Cell = {xPos = 0,
        yPos = 0
       }
local Cells = { {}, {} }
function Cell:new (o, xPos, yPos)
  o = o or {}
  -- начало первого варианта реализации
  self = {}
  setmetatable(o, self)
  self.__index = self
  self.xPos = xPos
  self.yPos = yPos
  -- конец первого варианта
  -- начало второго варианта реализации
  --[[
  setmetatable(o, o)
  o.__index = o
  o.xPos = xPos
  o.yPos = yPos
  --]]
  -- конец второго варианта
  return o
end

-- init matrix of cell class instances
for i = 1, 10, 1 do
  Cells[i] = {}
  for j = 1, 20, 1 do
    Cells[i][j] = Cell:new(nil, i, j)
  end
end

-- вывод нескольких элементов

for i = 1, 2, 1 do
  for j = 1, 2, 1 do
    print ("Cells["..i.."]["..j.."].xPos = "..Cells[i][j].xPos)
    print ("Cells["..i.."]["..j.."].yPos = "..Cells[i][j].yPos)
  end
end
```

возвращает:

```
Cells[1][1].xPos = 1
Cells[1][1].yPos = 1
Cells[1][2].xPos = 1
Cells[1][2].yPos = 2
Cells[2][1].xPos = 2
Cells[2][1].yPos = 1
Cells[2][2].xPos = 2
Cells[2][2].yPos = 2
```